# Script not work on joomla however it works perfectly on html page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to achieve scale in & scale out Onclick by using css transform property, as it suites for the responsive stuff.

I use a plugin of jquery which works fine one link mentioned below on simple html
http://techchef.co/devTest/test/

However it does'not work on the joomla website, while i am trying to use it, script shows perfectly on the site front end, i resolve all the conflict issues.but now it shows an error
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null*

If you inspect element on the below link you will find the error.

the script use the **base.js** which calls perfectly on the website
http://techchef.co/clients/Suitcase/index.php/travel/featurestravel

**here is the base.js file**
http://techchef.co/clients/Suitcase/templates/gk_music_free/js/base.js

Kindly guide me how it start working...It already took my whole day:(((

Comment: Look at your Developer console and identify the differences between the working sample and the broken sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console error says that `$('#new')` is "not an object".  So either `$` is not recognized as a jQuery object, jQuery is not loaded, or the `#new` element does not exist.  For you, it's the first item.

Your jQuery is using `jQuery.noConflict();` in the `head`, so you should use `jQuery` in place of the dollar sign `$`.

Also just to be safe I suggest that you enclose your jQuery code within a `document.ready`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery('#new').click(function () {
        jQuery('#test').animate({
            scale: '+=0.33'
        }, {
            queue: false, 
            duration: 1000
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

This will also work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // pass the "$" into the function
    $('#new').click(function () {
        $('#test').animate({
            scale: '+=0.33'
        }, {
            queue: false, 
            duration: 1000
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/42HNC/**

Comment: Hey Man ! thanks alot...Thank you So much you make my day...I will remember this

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try following;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#new').click(function () {$('#test').animate({scale: '+=0.33'}, {queue: false, duration: 1000});});
});


</script>
```